# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The type specified [com.sun.faces.application.WebappLifecycleListener] is not one of the expected listener types

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8

I got following problem: I got an application working with Java 8 and tomcat 7. Now I try to move on to tomcat 8. An a development env I downloaded the tomcat 8 binaries and startet working in eclipse. I added a new Server (Apache tomcat 8). Not I want to make my application running on the new tomcat 8. But I got following exceptions, which I can't fix:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener
WARNING: Catalina.start using conf/server.xml: Error at (28, 66) : org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener
```

This error seems logic to me, since the error message is really straight forward. After deleting this listener, following appears:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to 
start component [StandardEngine [Catalina]
.StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/mycontext]]
```

followed by:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The type specified [com.sun.faces.application.WebappLifecycleListener] is not one of the expected listener types
```

I got listener defined in Server.xml and I define listeners in my web.xml in my application. But if I comment all entries out, same error appears.

Could someone please give me any clues to solve my problem?

Comment: Your server.xml [is not compatible](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamkb/bamboo-does-not-start-after-upgrade-due-to-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-catalina-core-jasperlistener-836599885.html) with your tomcat version.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz, thank you for your comment, I also found the link you sent me, thats why I deleted the reference to the Jasper Listener, as I described in the first paragraph. But what is still incorrect?

Comment: Where is your server.xml? May be you are changing the wrong one.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz My server.xml is located in the tomcat Server Directory.

Comment: I have the same problem. I am upgrading my application from jsf 1.2 to 2.2 and spring 2 to 5. And there are a lot of changes i don't even know where i will change.

Comment: @AakashPatel hi Aakash, I could solve my problem! I checked every package I referenced in my code, then I found out, that some jsf packages I used together, are not longer compatible with each other on tomcat 8. So maybe this can help you too!

Comment: Hi @Ronaldo-CH Following are the changes I have made: Basically I have compared old jar with new jar and I have found that some of the classes that I have defined in web.xml are not in new jar, so i removed them. Than I found that I had 2 tld files (jsf_core, html_basic) in my project which were there in project. So i updated them and added new tld mojerra_ext. Also added spring-aop and spring-context jars, added org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener in web.xml and currently changing many more thing. Let me know what did yo change, so I can check on my side.