# Purpose of jsf-api.jar and jsf-impl.jar

Tags: jsf

I'm running into a question, which I can't resolve by myself. Following my setup:

Java Webapplication (uses Java Faces), developped with Java8 and Tomcat7, in production since 3 years. By randomly visting the website of tomcat, I saw the announcement "End of Life of Tomcat 8.0.x" which takes effect on June the 30th 2018. Now I try to move to tomcat 8.0.x first before I move to tomcat 8.5.x with my application.

Unfortunately, I got stoke with a kind of unspecific error message, descriped in issue  [ [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50964443/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-the-type-specified-com-sun-faces-applicatio?noredirect=1#comment88972655_50964443%20here) ]. By debuging step top step, I found the problem inside my application: **Java Faces libraries!**

In my Project dir: "project"\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib are following faces libraries:

- javax.faces.jar
- javax.faces-api-2.2.jar
- javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.1.jar
- javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-1.2.1.jar
- jsf-api.jar
- jsf-impl.jar

After deyploying my application to the new tomcat 8 server, the server cannot start up properly. Then I removed jsf-api.jar and jsf-impl.jar from application build path. Now, the application works! But I dont know why. I read about Java faces and all its libraries and saw issues describing the need of these two libraries. But actually, Java Faces only works on tomcat8 without these two libraries.

Could someone tell me the purpose of these two libraries and if there is really a need to include them, or not.

Comment: You effectively include 2 jsf versions/implementations javax.faces and javax.faces-api is one AND jsf-api and jsf-impl is the other. The difference in the api and impl (the newer ones don't have impl in the name) very often (mostly always) conflict and result in errors. If you had the same in tomcat 7 and it worked, you were lucky (but I cannot tell which version was used). Check which are the newer ones and use those.

Comment: Thank you for your explenations. @Kukeltje! I read this issue but was not secure, if it fits my questions.